# Get reference to control from another control befor setting properties (.Net winForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two controls in my form: HScrollBar and my own control:

```
 public class MainTextBox : RichTextBox
```

which overwrites some OnXChange methods, e.g. OnFontChanged. In this methods I have to have reference to the HScrollBar. The thing is that the proprties are being changed in the InitializeComponent and thus these methods are being called too.

So when inside InitializeComponent method this is called:

```
this.mainTextBox = new MainTextBox();
this.mainHScroll = new HScrollBar();

this.mainTextBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
//and so on
```

the OnFontChanged method is called, and inside this method i want reference to hScrollBar.

What is the best way to achive this?

Note this about .Net winForms, not asp.net

Comment: Isn't just making those things `public` enough?

Comment: Two ideas to do this: a) pass the instance in the constructor or b) write your own initialization method and pass the instance that way. You do have to call this function manually in your main form

Comment: @DonBoitnott Well, I think making things just public isn't proper. But even if I made my hScrollBar public how would I refer to it from other control?

Comment: @Michael I've tried to do this but it doesn't work since the controls are initialized inside InitializeComponent method AND there the properties are being set to them, while I have to have the reference. So I can't put my own construcor neither befor and after InitializeComponent and of course inside it.

Comment: Unless you're going to provide it through a proxy variable, it will be public.  That only leaves the exact way you choose to reference it:  by variable or through a reference to its form.

Comment: Then I you should roll your own Initialization method and call this method manually from your main forms constructor AFTER InitializeComponent have been called. That way all you required properties have been initialized and you can pass the instances to your own initialization method.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that's a solution, but it prevents menaging this control inside the vs designer.

Comment: Then you might try making your own usercontrol that contains both the textbox and the scrollbar?

Comment: @Michael not exacly, this example is simplified , actualy I have more controls and I want them to be independent. I'm looking for rather more clear and straight forward solution if it exeists.

Comment: One last idea... Have you tried `.FindForm()` or `.Parent` from inside the controls? I guess both gets valid after `InitializeComponents` - but I might be wrong

Comment: @Michael Nope, these are all (including TopMostControl) null at the time I need them. Also with your custom initialize proposition I don't only can't edit properties in designer but also the control isn't formated since at desing-time there is only called InitializeComponents.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am out of ideas now :(

Answer (score 1):

I do have another Idea... In your `MainTextBox` class add a public property of type `HScrollbar`. Add the `EditorBrowsable` attribute to it.
In the setter of this property in your `MainTextBox` class, call `OnFontChanged` if the value changes. Inside `OnFontChanged` check if the public `HScrollbar` property is null or not.

That way the normal `InitializeComponent` runs normally - without recognizing the `HScrollbar` property since it is null at that time. And in vs-desginer you will be able to assign an existing `HScrollbar` instance from the form to your `MainTextBox` and the change will trigger `OnFontChanged`.

Since I dont know what you want to do in OnFontChange I'll just change the `BackgroundColor` of the TextBox to test if the change will be visible in vs-designer:

```
public class MyTextBox: RichTextBox
{
    private HScrollBar m_bar;
    [EditorBrowsable]
    [Category("own")]
    public HScrollBar Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return m_bar;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_bar != value)
            {
                m_bar = value;
                OnFontChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        if (m_bar == null) return;
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is more or less what I did, although after seeing your answer. Shame that .net doesn't support such operations. Thanks for afford anyway.